# Python: defaultdict, Threading, Lock, Subfunction

Tags: python, multithreading

My app iterarting through the chunks of hosts and i am getting some data for this hosts, processing and updating some defaultdicts.

I am trying to update defaultdicts from Inner function using treading and Lock.

Here is some example of what i am doing:

```
from threading import Lock
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from collections import defaultdict

THREAD_LOCK = Lock()

def collect_data(self):
    data_1 = defaultdict(set)
    data_2 = defaultdict(list)

    def update_data(id_to_ips, risks):
        for id, ips in id_to_ips.items():
            data_1[id].update(ips)

        for ip, risk in risks.items():
            data_2[risk].append(ip)

    if self.thread_count:
        all_hosts = self._get_all_host()
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.thread_count) as executor:
            func = lambda x: list(self._get_data(x))
            for results in executor.map(func, all_hosts):
                for id_to_ips_dict, risks_dict in results:
                    with THREAD_LOCK:
                        update_data(id_to_ips_dict, risks_dict)

    else:
        for host_ids in self._get_all_host_ids():
            id_to_ips_dict, risks_dict = self._get_data(host_ids)
            update_data(id_to_ips_dict, risks_dict)

    return data_1, data_2
```

I know that updating defaultdict with THREAD LOCK is okay, but updating it from Inner function confuses me a bit.

What do you think?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: what's the definition of `func` function?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest get_all_hosts() func is generator which is yield chunk ( list of hosts ) , func  _get_data receive chunk, doing some requests to the API , processing response and return tuple (id_to_ips_dict, risks_dict)

Comment: And of course there is another loop i missed.            for results in executor.map(func, all_hosts):
                for id_to_ips_dict, risks_dict in results:
                    with THREAD_LOCK:
                        update_data(id_to_ips_dict, risks_dict)

Comment: @ok, can you also share `_get_data` definition ?